# Maximum number of vertices in undirected graph

Tags: graphs, time-complexity

I'm studying about time complexity of Kruskal's algorithm.

But there are two opinions to express time complexity as $O(|E|\lg|E|), O(|E|\lg|V|)$.

I know $O(|E|\lg|E|)$ is occurred from sorting by non-decreasing order of vertices.

But I don't understand of $O(|E|\lg|V|)$. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26744220/9437175) explains by $|E|\le|V|^2$, however from my knowledge, maximum number of vertices in undirected graph is $|E|\le\frac{|V|(|V|-1)}{2}$.

What is right time complexity for Kruskal's algorithm?

Comment: For a connected graph, the two running times you state are equivalent.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus That is I already said in the post.

Comment: So both running times are correct.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus My question is why connected graph of undirected graph has maximum number of vertices as $|V|^2$.

Comment: The maximum number of edges is $\binom{|V|}{2}$.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus What is the meaning of your notation? I saw first.

Comment: It's a binomial coefficient.

Comment: Then, what you mean is maximum number of edges is not $|V|^2$ but your notation?

Comment: Yes. The maximum number of edges is exactly what I wrote, which is smaller than $|V|^2$ for $|V| > 1$. But the bound $|V|^2$ is also correct (if not tight), and suffices for the purpose of determining the asymptotic running time of the algorithm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kruskal's algorithm is only applied to connected graphs. These have at least $|V|-1$ edges. On the other hand, the complete graph has $\binom{|V|}{2}$ edges, and so
$$
|V|-1 \leq |E| \leq \binom{|V|}{2}.
$$
The left-hand side is $\Omega(|V|)$ and the right-hand side is $O(|V|^2)$. Therefore $\log |E| = \Theta(\log |V|)$. For this reason, the two quoted running times $O(|E| \log |E|)$ and $O(|E| \log |V|)$ are completely identical — on connected graphs, an algorithm has running time $O(|E| \log |E|)$ iff it has running time $O(|E| \log |V|)$.

Comment: Thank you for your excellent answer! Then, what is the answer of binomial coefficent? Is it almost $|V|^2$ and why? If it bothers you, just skip it. It is enough to your sincere answer.

Comment: The binomial coefficient is roughly $|V|^2/2$. Its exact value is $|V|(|V|-1)/2$.

Comment: Oh it is what I said in the post, so $|E| \le |V|(|V|-1)/2 \lt |V|^2$?

Comment: Yes, these inequalities are valid.

Comment: How can I good at algorithm or overall computer science like you? I'm Junior grade of Korean college and I want to improve my skills. I'm impressed by your solid knowldege.

Comment: Follow your course of studies, and eventually you will know more. At any rate, this is not for the comment section.

Comment: Ok, I understood. I have one more question about time complexity of prim algorithm. Can I ask or just write the post?

Comment: No, you'd have to write a new post.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your continuous comments